# how to dissable internal mic in lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, pulseaudio

I have MSI notebook with Realtek ALC882 sound card.
I want to record from line in but in Pavucontrol
the intenal mic volume setting  follows the in line volume 
setting so the fan noise is recorded.The mic and internal are muted
in Alsamixer,there is not internal mic option.
I can not find possibility to dissable mic in Bios (A1039ATE V1.5A)
Can anybody help?
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I have unistalled Pulse and played with alsa mixer folloving this article :http://www.audiomisc.co.uk/Linux/ALSA/ALSAforUsers.html
I do not know what I did exactly,but now I can record from line in without
disturbing internal mic noise.
Probably I set it by changing the input source options in Alsamixer.
Martin